# AES 256 encryption by passing IV

Tags: java, c#, encryption, aes

I am tiring to converting encription logic in to java which written in C#. I pass a custom IV as parameter.

```
 private static byte[] iv = new byte[] { 116,209,63,154,85,66,37,82,96,104,131,192,103,140,125,176 };
```

But, In java can not hold more then 128 in a byte array. In C# it is possible.

```
        this.secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        this.iv = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        this.cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM_AES256);
```

In javax.crypto IvParameterSpec constactory only allow byte array as "iv". Can anyone please help for pass above byte[] as iv parameter in java.

Comment: [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346101/java-how-to-use-byte-literals-greater-than-0x7f) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241336/initialize-unsigned-byte-array-using-hex-number) that could be considered duplicates.

Comment: You should not use static IV's in the first place. Static IV's are useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Java does not support [unsigned datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430346/why-doesnt-java-support-unsigned-ints), while .NET does.

Unsigned byte is from 0 to 255. This is .NET [Byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.aspx) struct
Signed byte is from -128 to 127. This is Java [byte](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html) primitive datatype or .NET [SByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.sbyte.aspx) struct.

The data in .Net code stores the iv as unsigned values, while Java code does not allow you to do it directly.

**Solutions:**

1) You could just manually subtract 128 from each byte in .NET code, thus making it to represent the same bit pattern(IV is just sequence of bits - it does not matter whether they stored as signed or unsigned values - it is the bits that must match):

```
byte[] iv = new byte[] { -8, 81, ...};
```

2) Or you could store the same data in an int datatype array and convert them to byte values using the following code.

```
int[] ivInInts = new int[] { 116,209,63,154,85,66,37,82,96,104,131,192,103,140,125,176 };

byte[] iv = new byte[ivInInts.getLength()];

for (int i = 0; i < ivInInts.getLength(); i++)
   iv = (byte)(ivInInts[i] - 128);
```

**EDIT:**

If you have some doubts about binary equivalence of numbers you could read about [two's complement numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement):

65 = 0100 0001 as unsigned byte = 0100 0001 as signed byte
-65 = cannot be represented as unsigned byte = 1011 1111 as signed byte
193 = 1011 1111 as unsigned byte = cannot be represented as signed byte

Comment: Thanks Eugene, If we subtract -128 from each element in the array the result array will have (-) value not the same what it pass in C#. Is that ok?

Comment: @Eugene Podskal You're not correct. Unsigned 8-bit integer is from 0 to 255, and the signed 8-bit integer or sbyte is from -128 to 127. Please, correct it.

Comment: @GoRoS Thank you. Just misplaced the strings.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to Eugene's proposal: simply explicitly convert all values - or the values above 127 - by casting to a `byte`. It's also a good idea to use hexadecimals for binary data.

```
byte[] test = new byte[] { 0, (byte) 0, 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 128, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 256, (byte) 0x100 };
```

Note that - as the value of the last two bytes should make clear - this does allow you to specify values that are out of range without raising a warning.

Alternatively, you could use a hexadecimal or base64 decoder, so you can create more dense byte array representation using strings.